# How to unbind a jquery plugin in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a jquery plugin in my code which will force the input box to accept only numeric input but at some point I have to disable that and make it accept alphabets also. I cannot use unbind() because it will unbind other features as well. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mpr73v9w/ and below is my code.

```
<input type="text">
<button>Button</button>

$.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;

            if (e.shiftKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
            return (
                key == 8 ||
                key == 9 ||
                key == 13 ||
                key == 46 ||
                (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
    });
};

$("input").ForceNumericOnly();

$("button").click(function() {
    $('input').ForceNumericOnly.destroy();
});
```

Comment: write a separate function for alphanumeric validation -unbind numeric and bind alphanumeric when you want ?

Comment: Amit.rk3 I cannot use unbind because it is unbinding other features as well. I just want to disable that plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the named event method `$.keydown()` you can use the `$.on()` method which allows event namespaces.

```
$(this).on('keydown.forcenumericonly', function(e) { 
    // handle event
});
```

This makes it easy to unbind specific events without interfaring with other features. Do this with the `.off()` method.

```
$.fn.ForceNumericOnly.destroy = function () {
    $(this).off('.forcenumericonly');
};
```

You can unbind only the `keydown` event with `$(this).off('keydown.forcenumericonly')` or as in the example unbind all events in the `forcenumericonly` namespace with `$(this).off('.forcenumericonly')`.